# Using expokit.zgexpv after compiling via f2py

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fortran, f2py

I want to compute expressions such as exp(At)v, where A is a complex, scipy.sparse.csr matrix, t is a real number and v is a numpy one-dimensional array of complex numbers.

Currently I have a file [expokit.f][1] that has a subroutine ZGEXPV around line #2420 (see link). It also has some f2py intent connotations. I compiled expokit.f using `f2py -c expokit.f -m expokit --link-blas_opt --link-lapack_opt` and the compilation didn't give errors.

There is a [test][2] file for a different function (`expokit.zgpadm`) within expokit.f that executes  as expected well on my Ubuntu machine, but I am interested in the `expokit.zgexpv` function.

When I `import expokit` in Python after the f2py compile and do `numpy.info(expokit.zgexpv)`, I get the following output:

```
>>> np.info(expokit.zgexpv)
zgexpv(m,t,v,w,tol,anorm,wsp,iwsp,matvec,itrace,iflag,[n,lwsp,liwsp,matvec_extra_args])

Wrapper for ``zgexpv``.

Parameters
----------
m : input int
t : input float
v : input rank-1 array('D') with bounds (n)
w : in/output rank-1 array('D') with bounds (n)
tol : in/output rank-0 array(float,'d')
anorm : input float
wsp : input rank-1 array('D') with bounds (lwsp)
iwsp : input rank-1 array('i') with bounds (liwsp)
matvec : call-back function
itrace : input int
iflag : in/output rank-0 array(int,'i')

Other Parameters
----------------
n : input int, optional
    Default: len(v)
lwsp : input int, optional
    Default: len(wsp)
liwsp : input int, optional
    Default: len(iwsp)
matvec_extra_args : input tuple, optional
    Default: ()

Notes
-----
Call-back functions::

  def matvec(n,e_wsp_j1v_n_err,e_wsp_j1v_err): return
  Required arguments:
    n : input int
    e_wsp_j1v_n_err : input complex
    e_wsp_j1v_err : input complex
```

Now my goal is to be able to pass input to the function as follows (Python3):

```
n=2000
m=30 #(m denotes the number of Krylov steps in the expokit.zgexpv )
A=scipy.sparse.rand(n,n,density=0.01) + 1.0j  * scipy.sparse.rand(n,n,density=0.01)
v=np.random.rand(n) + 1.0j * np.random.rand(n) #the vector v on which exp(At) acts.

t=1.0
tol=1e-07
itrace=np.array([0])
iflag=np.array([0])
MXLIM=200000
iwsp=np.zeros(MXLIM).astype(int) #sufficiently large array
wsp=np.zeros(MXLIM) #sufficiently large array
nrmA=scipy.linalg.norm(A)

def matvec(n,x,y):
    y = A @ x

answer=expokit.zgexpv(m,t,v,w,tol,nrmA,wsp,iwsp,matvec,itrace,iflag) #answer should be exp(At)v
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong here. It would be great if someone could correct my above-mentioned code. I am almost certain my `matvec` function is at fault, among possibly other things.
[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tvsbBqhsonkVgUbzX0jd5a5uABk2YgS9/view?usp=sharing
[2]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hqQjzN_bvT-P-fKFzxwJYcaAgqgX84aj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] Please show more of your code in your question, do not use external links too your google drive, the code must remain available in the future. It is really important.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises as expokit's matvec subroutine is called as follows

```
call matvec(n,  wsp(j1v-n), wsp(j1v) )
```

Thus, f2py supplies to your own (python) matvec function only an integer, a complex, and another complex.
Note those complex are scalars and not vectors of length n.

I hope that this comment helps someone to actually find an answer.

---

There is another minor error in your code.
`scipy.linalg.norm` does not work with sparse matrices.
You need to call the following

```py
nrmA=scipy.sparse.linalg.norm(A)
```

Comment: Not having the code you are referring to it is hard to guess, but passing an array element instead of the array itself is normally allowed, depending on the exact details.